# What does Void() in Swift 4 mean in PromiseKit?

Tags: ios, void, swift4, promisekit

What does `Void` in Swift 4 mean?
If I have a function to `fulfill`, as follows:

```
func someFunc() -> Promise<Void> {
    fulfill()
}
```

an error shows, and it only works if:

```
fulfill(Void())
```

**Note**. Swift 3 supported:

```
fulfill()
```

I am using Swift 4, but can someone help explain why `Void` in Swift 4 has a constructor?

Comment: FYI this is probably a Swift 4 bug (well, some on Swift team have told me it's intended, but I expect it will be “fixed” due to this kind of confusion eventually). Also you need not specify `Void`, `fulfill(())` will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Void` is defined as an *empty tuple* in Swift. You can take a look [swift-void](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/void).